# How to create and use and external derby Database

Tags: java, database, external, derby

am getting started with Java database development and i wanted to know how to create and use database outside of the Derby server so for example instead of using this as a host url :

```
 String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
```

i want to use something like this :

```
 String host = "jdbc:derby://c:/MyDb/Employees";
```

i dunno if that is correct or not, but this is what am trying to do cause i don't know how to use the database in the localhost after exporting the executable jar for the application

thank you

Comment: Do you want to load database from local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load database from the file system, you use:

```
String host = "jdbc:derby:c:/MyDb/Employees";
```

See the [examples](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/rdevdvlp22102.html#rdevdvlp22102).

Comment: thank you, just one more question, is there a big difference between the 2 types ? specially after exporting the Jar file and using it in another computer

Comment: If you set up jdbc connection as a local file access, then you don't use any port, and IO delays are shorter. For the application which comes with it's own database I would rather use local file jdbc configuration instead of URL configuration.